# Unable to perform decryption using PKCS#11 interface for usb token

Tags: c#, .net, pkcs#11

We are trying to perform data encryption and decryption with a HyperPKI HYP2003 usb token in a .Net application.
For data encryption we have used the ‘BouncyCastle’ library for .Net and has used the algorithm ‘RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding’ and which was successful.
However for the decryption part we are using the PKCS#11 interface.

```
IMechanism mechanism = 
session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_RSA_PKCS);
using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(data), outputStream = new 
MemoryStream()) {
    session.Decrypt(mechanism, foundObjects[0], inputStream, outputStream);
    decryptedData = outputStream.ToArray();
}
```

But upon trying we are getting an error ‘CKR_GENERAL_ERROR’, and unable to proceed further. Our efforts to use .net's native cryptographic libraries have failed hence we are resorting to PKCS11 interface.

As per the developer's guide for this device, the only supported public key algorithms are ‘CKM_RSA_PKCS’, ‘CKM_RSA_X_509’, ‘CKM_RSA_PKCS_OAEP’. Has anyone come across this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You mentioned code that you did not share; please read [mre].